Developing a react native application that is using pedometer of android and ios mobile
I am using this library to count steps in react native mobile app. Issue is that my application is receiving wrong data. As I got in my server that a user walk 80k steps instantly. So I put log using mixpanel and got to know that this library return steps like this 3,6,9,.....200, 5000, ....
So there is something wrong with it but inside ios code of library it is just returning what it got from CMPedometer in ios.
Is it possible that sensor returns wrong steps or user can do some cheating. My app is already not working on jailbreak devices.
